# Unable to upload product image [4MB]

Tags: product, image, upload

I have developed a magento website and I'm facing a serious issue while uploading the product image !
I am unable to upload images more then 2MB of size !

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have updated your php.ini to allow the desired size of files. A good example of this can be found on [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184541/2054777)

```
upload_max_filesize=2M
post_max_size=8M
```

*Note: post_max_size should be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize*

Comment: Unable to change php.ini.sample to php.ini. Throws me error ! Any help ?

Comment: @Kunal you do not need to change the whole file, just find the to mentioned in my answer and update these to the value you need.

Comment: I did the same bro ! Updated the values still I'm unable to upload large size images ! Do you think it's something wrong with Godaddy ? Maybe it's shared hosting so it's creating an issue ? If you can help me with this ! My skype is e.u.c.l.i.d

Comment: I would suggest contacting godaddy about this one. It will be a common request that they will be able to help with.

Comment: Yeah exact point,Thank you.This solved for me

Answer (score -1):

If your webserver is Apache and mod_security module is installed, please remove and check again.